# Custom NewForm , Redirect to a custom page using Powershell

Tags: powershell, splist-custom-newform

I could achieve this i.e. creating a list's NewForm named CustomNewForm.aspx setting it as Default NewForm and editing it in advanced mode to add a script code which redirects to CustomForm.aspx Page using code
`window.location.href = "/sites/<Site Collection Name>/SitePages/CustomForm.aspx"`

Using SharePoint Designer but as per deployment is concerned I need to achieve this using Powershell only. Is there a way to do the above two steps using Powershell or is there a better solution to achieve the task of mainly to redirect to CustomForm Page (The CustomForm.aspx page has custom UI and consist of jsom code to create a new ListItem) for creating new item in the list and making it available on the click of New item button.

Comment: Do you want to redirect after item is saved?

Comment: No before, actually at page load itself

Comment: searched for creating a list form using powershell didn't get relevant solutions

Comment: What is your environment SPO or SP on-prem?

Comment: SPO environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following CSOM code to update the `NewFormUrl` property of the list item content type.

```
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://spm:5002/sites/test");
            Web web = ctx.Web;
            List test = web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");
            ContentTypeCollection ct = test.ContentTypes;
            ctx.Load(ct);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            ContentType item = ct.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("Item")).FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ", " + item.Id + ", " + item.NewFormUrl);
            item.NewFormUrl = "SitePages/asd.aspx";
            item.Update(false);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now whenever you click on `New Item` it will open the desired page. Also note that `item.Update(false);` statement is going to update the content type. The `false` as function parameter used to not update the derived content type.